# Add date object in a relative path?

Tags: python, relative-path

I'm currently trying to create PDF from Excel file in Python, with the hour and date of creation of the PDF on the name's file. But I'm stuck with the relative path:

```
output_file = str(path)+"\\Perception-demandeur.pdf"
```

How could I add a date object in my relative path? Just below part of my code.

```
path = Path(__file__).parent
input_file = str(path)+"\\preparation-pdf-perception.xlsx"
# give your file name with valid path
persopdf = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S")
output_file = str(path)+"\\Perception-demandeur.pdf"
#output_file = f"/10DBA/Perception-demandeur-{persopdf}.pdf"
# give valid output file name and path
app = client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
app.Interactive = False
app.Visible = False
Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(input_file)
try:
    Workbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, output_file)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to convert in PDF format.Please confirm environment meets all the requirements  and try again")
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more, what the problem is? I see, that you are currently already creating a string with the current date in it but don't actually use it in the path. Do you have problems in getting the required format in this string, or how to put it into the path?

Comment: Your question is about constructing a path, so please take *everything* else unrelated to that out of your question and provide only a bare [mre].

Comment: Hello @Christian, thanks for your comment, when I try to do that: output_file = str(path)+"\\Perception-demandeur+persopdf+.pdf", i get an error like that: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Document not saved.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2147024773), None)

Comment: Hello @martineau, thanks for your answer, and yes sorry for the too long code. the problem is only on output_file, when I try to add persopdf, which is the date, I get an error: output_file= str(path)+"\\Perception-demandeur+persopdf+.pdf", i get an error like that: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Document not saved.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2147024773), None)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment I'll try to make an answer:

You have the following as the formating: `now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S")`
This would, as of right now, produce the string "14/01/2022-10:50:46".
But windows does not allow slashes nor colons in file names. So you would have to find another date format. Maybe something like `now.strftime("%d%m%Y %H-%M-%S")`, which will get you "14012022 10-50-46".

Or, to make it more sortable: `now.strftime("%Y%m%d %H-%M-%S")` for "20220114 10-50-46"

Comment: Thanks again Christian, when I add persopdf formating like you show, I get this error always: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Document not saved.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2147024773), None). I update the line like that:                            
persopdf = now.strftime("%d%m%Y-%H:%M:%S")
output_file = str(path)+"\\Perception-demandeur"+persopdf+".pdf"

Comment: Just to be sure - did you remove the colons? I forgot to mention that at first, but they probably should also be replaced with something else.

Comment: Also I have one more hint: You are using the Path object a bit wrong here. This here str(path)+"\\Perception-demandeur.pdf" should better read as "path / 'Perception-demandeur.pdf'". Then you don't have to worry about the direction of the slash on different platforms, because the path object takes care of that.

Comment: I forgot the colons, now it works perfectly!! Thanks a lot Christian, you saved my day!!

Comment: @SebastienDucher You are welcome :) If you could just accept my answer, that would be great.

Comment: It's accepted! :) thanks again!